# Split strings from multiple columns into New Rows Respectively in R or SQLite

Tags: r, sqlite, r-markdown

I was wondering if there was any way in R to split strings from multiple columns into multiple rows respectively. For example:

Split something from: `V1     V2     V3
                     1    A,B,C   C,D,F
                     2    X,Y,Z   V,U,`

Into                    `V1     V2     V3
     1      A      C
     1      B      D
     1      C      F
     2      X      V 
.... 2      Z      NA`

and so on. I was able to it for the first column, but the second column just prints duplicates of what is in the first column. I am using R so I can use either R syntax of SQLite syntax. Thank you!

Here is what I have so far:

```
split<- strsplit(as.character(Start), as.character(End), split= ";")

split1<-data.frame(id = rep(dataset$id, sapply(split, length)), End = unlist(split), End=unlist(split))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `separate_rows` from `tidyr` in `R`

```
library(tidyr)
separate_rows(df1, V2, V3)
#   V1 V2 V3
#1  1  A  C
#2  1  B  D
#3  1  C  F
#4  2  X  V
#5  2  Y  U
#6  2  Z  T

separate_rows(df2, V2, V3)
#   V1 V2 V3
#1  1  A  C
#2  1  B  D
#3  1  C  F
#4  2  X  V
#5  2  Y  U
#6  2  Z
```

---

Another option is `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df2, 2:ncol(df2), ",", "long")
```

#### data

```
df2 <- structure(list(V1 = 1:2, V2 = c("A,B,C", "X,Y,Z"), V3 = c("C,D,F", 
"V,U,")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: @Chioma  I am using `tidyr_0.6.0`.  Please check if you have the updated tidyr or not.  If not, update the package

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of tidyr.  `separate_rows` was introduced in 0.5.0

Comment: @akrun Okay thanks! How do I make it so that when the columns do not match, like in the last example I printed, that R prints "NA" or is just empty?

Comment: @Chioma  It gives me a blank value by default using the new example you showed

Comment: @Chioma I am not getting any error.  Please check my update

Comment: @akrun could it be because in the example I gave I included a comma after the last input (V,U,) in reality there would not be a comma there. It would just be V,U Could that be why  I am getting the error?

Comment: @Chioma  In that case, use the `cSplit`, it works with or without commas at the end

Comment: @akrun Thank you! For some reason, R is printing an extra amount of rows where both column 2 and column 3 have values NA. I'm not sure why but my observation has bumped up from around 3500 to 33000. I really appreciate all your help! I am in the process of learning and every step seems to be following by twice the errors.

Comment: @Chioma Based on the examples you provided, it works fine for me.